# Can I use a moss support for my Hoya Plant?

Tags: houseplants, support

My Hoya has been hanging for most of its life. Recently, we moved and there are no hanging spots with enough light. Currently, it is sprawled out on my counter, but I would prefer more structure. Can I use a moss support to structure my Hoya??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its Hoya carnosa or one of its varieties, then yes, you can use a moss stick, but wires or a fine trellis will do the same job, it doesn't have to be a moss stick. Hoya bella, though, a more miniature variety, is better grown as a trailer, and I'm not sure which Hoya you've got because there are no flowers present currently, although the size of some of the leaves suggest it's likely H. carnosa.